# Create a Grid with buttons using knockout.js in MVC 3 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

Hi all I want to create a grid using knockout.js in MVC 3 razor, I have 3 columns in grid first column should be of button and the rest of the columns should get data from the controller.

The thing is that I am able to achieve all this but I am not able set class or id attribute to the button in the grid. I want the class to be "select" where as the id of the button should be the value in the subsequent column, so that I can perform some client side scripting using jQuery.

my cshtml page is

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Buttons</th>
                <th data-bind="text: column1"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: column2"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Office">
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Select"/></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My viewModel is like this

```
var OfficeGrp = function(){
var self =this;
self.name = ko.observable();
self.location = ko.observable(); 
}
var OfficeVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Office = ko.observableArray([new OfficeGrp()]);
    self.column1= ko.observable("Name");
    self.column2= ko.observable("Location");
    self.RadioBtnActive = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Office.removeAll();
        $.getJSON(urlContent + "Office/GetOfficeGrid", { param: "true" }, function (data) {
            self.Office(data);
        });
    };
    self.RadioBtnAll = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Office.removeAll();
         $.getJSON(urlContent + "Office/GetOfficeGrid", { param: "true" }, function (data) {
            self.Office(data);
        });
    };

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var officeVM = new OfficeVM();
    ko.applyBindings(officeVM );
     officeVM.RadioBtnActive();
     $("input:button[class='select']").click(function () {
        alert('HELLO');
    });

});
```

Even though I explicitly assign class to button element like this

jQuery click event which I have given does not get hit upon click of button

```
$("input:button[class='select']").click(function () {
    alert('HELLO');
});
```

I have tried using this from knockout.js

```
<input type="button" value="Select" class="select" data-bind="attr: { id: name}"/>
```

but I first want jQuery Button click event to work which is not working (I don't know why) upon which I would like to send the value of the id to controller.  A help in this case would be highly appreciated..........

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Grid with buttons using konckout.js in mvc 3 razor cshtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635805/create-a-grid-with-buttons-using-konckout-js-in-mvc-3-razor-cshtml)