# Create a Grid with buttons using konckout.js in mvc 3 razor cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

Hi all i want to create a grid using konckout.js in mvc 3 razor, i have 3 columns in grid first column should be of button and the rest of the columns should get data from the controller.The thing is that i am able to achieve all this but i am not able set class or id attribute to the button in the grid.I want the class to be "select" where as the id of the button should be the value in the subsequent column, so that i can perform some client side scriptings using jquery. my cshtml page is

```
    <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Buttons</th>
        <th data-bind="text: column1"></th>
        <th data-bind="text: column2"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Office">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Select"/></td>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My viewModel is like this

```
    var OfficeGrp = function(){
var self =this;
self.name = ko.observable();
self.location = ko.observable(); 
}
var OfficeVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Office = ko.observableArray([new OfficeGrp()]);
    self.column1= ko.observable("Name");
    self.column2= ko.observable("Location");
    self.RadioBtnActive = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Office.removeAll();
        $.getJSON(urlContent + "Office/GetOfficeGrid", { param: "true" }, function (data) {
            self.Office(data);
        });
    };
    self.RadioBtnAll = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Office.removeAll();
         $.getJSON(urlContent + "Office/GetOfficeGrid", { param: "true" }, function (data) {
            self.Office(data);
        });
    };

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var officeVM = new OfficeVM();
    ko.applyBindings(officeVM );
     officeVM.RadioBtnActive();
     $("input:button[class='select']").click(function () {
        alert('HELLO');
    });

});
```

Even though i explictly assign class to button element like this

```
    <input type="button" value="Select" class="select"/>
```

Jquery click event which i have given does not get hit upon click of button

```
    $("input:button[class='select']").click(function () {
        alert('HELLO');
    });
```

I have tried using this from knockout.js

```
    <input type="button" value="Select" class="select" data-bind="attr: { id: name}"/>
```

And also the radio buttons i forgot to add at the beginning

```
    <input id="RadiobtnActive" type="radio" name="radioBtn" checked="checked" class="rdbtn" data-bind="click: RadioBtnActive"/>Active
   <input id="RadiobtnAll" type="radio" name="radioBtn" class="rdbtn" data-bind="click: RadioBtnAll"/> All
```

but i first want Jquery Button click event to work which is not working(i don't know why) upon which i would like to send the value of the id to controller.  A help in this case would be highly appreciated..........

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Grid with buttons using konckout.js in mvc 3 razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635360/create-a-grid-with-buttons-using-konckout-js-in-mvc-3-razor)

Comment: I think your ko.applybindings are overriding your jquery bindings

Comment: if thats the case i've also tried using delegate and on method,in both cases it doesn't work.....

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try to see this tutorial

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html